# Evaluate $\oint_{C}xy^2dx+2x^2 dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> $$\oint_{C}xy^2dx+2x^2y dy$$
>   triangle:$$C=\{(0,0),(2,2),(2,4)\}$$

**My attempt:**

Using Green's theorem

$$\oint_{C}\underbrace{xy^2}_{P}dx+\underbrace{2x^2y}_{Q} dy=\iint\bigg(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\bigg)$$

$$=\iint\bigg(2xy \bigg)dxdy$$

$$=\int_{y=0}^{y=2}\bigg[\int_{x=y/2}^{x=y}\bigg(2xy\bigg)dx\bigg]dy+\int_{y=2}^{y=4}\bigg[\int_{x=y/2}^{x=2}\bigg(2xy\bigg)dx\bigg]dy$$

$$=\dots =3+9=\boxed{12}$$

> Is it correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **NOTE:**
>
> The solution herein addressed the Originally Posted Question, which questioned the evaluation of the line integral $\oint_C (xy^2\,dx+2x^2\,dy)$.  Since this post, the OP edited the question to request verifying evaluation of the line integral $\oint_C (xy^2\,dx+2x^2y\,dy)$.

---

**REPLY TO THE ORIGINALLY ASKED QUESTION**

In using Green's Theorem, one term was omitted.  The correct way forward is

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C (xy^2\,dx+2x^2\,dy)&=\int_0^2\int_{x}^{2x} \left(\frac{\partial (2x^2)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (xy^2)}{\partial y}\right)dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^2\int_{x}^{2x} (4x-2xy)dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^2 (4x^2-3x^3)\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac43
\end{align}$$

---

We can check this by carrying out the line integral directly.  To that end, we write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C (xy^2\,dx+2x^2\,dy)&=\int_0^2 (x^3+2x^2)\,dx\\\\
&+\int_0^2 8\,dy\\\\
&+\int_2^0 (4x^3+4x^2)\\\\
&=\frac{28}{3}+16+\left(-16-\frac{32}{3}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac43
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Sorry, I edited the quation, it should be $2x^2\color{blue}ydy$